# Filter places by type using PlaceFilter() with Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-places-api

I can't find any examples of PlaceFilter in use.
Perhaps you should not use it at all?
This is what I've tried so far.

```
val placeFilter = PlaceFilter(false, mutableListOf("restaurant"))
```

or

```
val placeFilter = PlaceFilter(false, mutableListOf(Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT.toString()))
```

then I pass it to

```
val placeResults = mPlaceDetectionClient.getCurrentPlace(placeFilter)
```

and get no result in my

```
placeResults.onCompleteListener{}
```

How do i use filters correctly?
Should I use it at all?
My app rates restaurants and all other places are redundant to the user.

Comment: According to the docs for PlaceFilter, the second parameter is the ID (see https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceFilter ). So apparently, you won't be able to filter by type using this method (see what IDs look like here : https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-id ). So the best way could be to ask for all the places in the area, and filter yourself based on place.getPlaceTypes()

Comment: Thanks, your a life saver!

Not knowing it's time to give up is dangerous.